# Get row/column index while looping with numel

Tags: matlab

I am just approaching Matlab, is there a way to get the row- and column-indices from  `i` while looping with `numel`?
I mean for each cycle `1:numel(B)`, get the relevant variable for the value of row and column:

```
for i = 1:numel(B)
 rowIndex= ??
 colIndex= ??

    ...my stuff...

 end
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  How are you supposed to get row and column indices with just `i`?  Do you have vectors that store this information? What is `B`?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, B is a 2D matrix of unknown dimensions.

Comment: That makes more sense.  Just use `ind2sub`.  The answer below provides what you need.

Comment: Note that when it comes to Matlab this approach is probably the wrong one.

Comment: I second Forss, it seems very possible that what you trying to do stays way behind its possibilities performance wise. [**Maybe this article is interesting for you**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) which converts a [linear index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) `i` to row and column subscripts given the size of the matrix:

```
[rowIndex, colIndex] = ind2sub(size(B), i)
```

Because `ind2sub` can [return multiple values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html#btexm36), the row index is assigned directly to `rowIndex` and the column to `colIndex`.

Comment: The indices will be assigned to `rowIndex` and `colIndex` separately. This should do exactly what you want.